# Isolating game server instances on a single linux machine

Tags: linux, multiple-instances, gameserver

Beloved community of StackExchange, I'm in need of your help.

I'm trying to come up with the most efficient way to isolate game server instances on a single box. For now the setup includes a debian linux distro and let's say minecraft bukkit servers coupled with a web server that displays resource usage per instance. At this point I'm considering building a wrapper around each process, but is it the most efficient and flexible way?

Now here lies the problem. Limiting I can handle, but I can't think of a way to spoof the resources available to the instance. As some may know, bukkit allows plugin usage, which can view system spec with ease.
I may just be blind and overlook the obvious, so please, if You have even a slightest suggestion, go ahead and let me know.

Cheers

Comment: Such as containers?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Sweet, looks like it could work. Weird part is I hadn't heard of it before. Much thanks mate